# making inline-block elements stay on same line

Tags: css, sass

I have a simple site:

- I've defined two small classes: `row` and `column`.
- I have HTML with one row and two columns.

I want to force the ensure the columns appear on the same row, even if it goes past the bounds of the screen.

Here's how the page looks when it's zoomed out quite a bit (clearly, they are not on the same horizontal line like I want them to be):
[image]

Here is a Codepen to reproduce / play around with the code:

https://codepen.io/maxpleaner/pen/KmXbRX

Here is the HTML markup (with .slim preprocessor):

```
#examples
  #example-1.row
    iframe.column{
      src='http://localhost:3000'
    }
    .explanation.column on the left is an iframe
```

Here's the style (with .sass preprocessor)

```
  body, html
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    overflow-x: scroll

  @mixin cell-height
    height: 300px

  @mixin cell-width
    width: 300px

  @mixin inline-block
    display: inline-block

  @mixin nowrap
    whitespace: nowrap

  @mixin default-spacing
    padding: 10px
    margin: 10px

  .row
    display: block

  .column
    border: 1px solid black
    @include cell-width
    @include cell-height
    @include inline-block
    @include nowrap
    @include default-spacing
```

I should mention that I tried adding `float: left` to the `.column` style. It looks correct *when the page is zoomed out*, but on a mobile device it still appears on two lines. I want it to *stretch the page horizontally* if it doesn't fit (so the user will have to scroll left/right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following rule:

```
.explanation.column
  vertical-align: top
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPWqQa

Comment: The result seems to be the same as when I add `float: left`. It looks correctly when the page is zoomed out, but when it's too small then the page doesn't stretch horizontally.

Comment: @maxple, not sure I follow. I thought you only wanted the 2 boxes align vertically? Can you screenshot the problem?

Comment: Figured it out. You solved half the problem, the other part was that I needed to add a fixed width/height to the body/html (i.e. 100px not 100%)

Answer (score 7):

You can force `display: inline-block / inline` items to stay on the same row, using `white-space: nowrap` on the container ([demo](https://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/QvqzPO)):

```
.row
  display: block
  white-space: nowrap
```

Or use the `@include nowrap` mixin you've got.

In addition, as suggested in [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810983/5157454), you should align the the two elements to the top using:

```
.explanation.column
  vertical-align: top
```

Comment: You should add that you also used part of my solution with `vertical-align: top`

Comment: @Chris - he updated his original pen, which I've forked, with your solution. Missed that, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Oh. Sorry didn't know.

Comment: It's good knowledge that the no-wrap would conceptually go on the row, not the column in this case. But the specific problem at hand seems to hinge on whether or not vertical-align was used.